# Discussion of the Java SocketChannel, performance

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, channel

I am currently investigating the performance of SocketChannel.

In details, if I have a SocketChannel such like:

```
SocketChannel sc = Selectionkey.channel();
```

And I have a bytebuffer to send,

```
sc.write(buffer);
```

Then what would determine the time consumed by the write() function?

In detail, what I am asking is something happens in bottom layer, or saying, the detailed implementation of this method. What signals the successful the write() function? Is it waiting for the ack packet from the other end?

Thanks

Comment: It's implementation specific. As you can see, `SocketChannel` is abstract, and it's `write(ByteBuffer)` method is as well. This means the way `write` works may change depending on the implementation.

Comment: I know, but if I call Selctor.open() to get a socket channel, and I use it to connect a network address, then what is the implementation of that channel?

Comment: @VinceEmigh The thing I want to know is what is the write method waiting for, if I want to send data via network. It just seems cost too much time in my program, and it is latency-dependent, so I guess it is waiting for the ack pakcet??????

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you were to show us what you were doing (what's in the buffer, where that send call is at, ect...). You should not have to worry about implementation details. If you'd like to look, it seems `SocketChannelImpl` is the implementation class. But it's best you step through your program's execution with a debugger to find exactly which call (possibly within the `write` method) is causing the halt to locate the problem quicker.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I am sending a 16bytes data in one machine, and receive it in the other, the data is all 0, so you needn't worry about it. I found the sending rate is high when two threads run in local machine, and low when run in separate. So I guess this may because the latency is different (both on local, low latency). But essentially, what depends on the network condition in my code, is exactly write() function, and thus I am seeking the answer if the write(buf) in channel is waiting for something, perhaps ACK?

Comment: @VinceEmigh By the way, I set the socketchannel to work in non-blocking mode. It is said that in non-blocking mode, the write function will return without consideration of how many bytes are written, but it still looks like 'blocking' in my case.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use your IDE's debugger. Find which call within the `write` call hierarchy is causing the halt. Eclipse has a step filter, you can jump into method calls (if you attached the source). The `write` call hierarchy leads to native methods. If something is happening at that low of a level, then it a problem with your network or a bug. I doubt it's a bug, but if it is, we would need to know things like your version of Java, exactly which call is causing the problem, ect... (continued on next comment)

Comment: You are not giving us enough information, and you cannot expect someone to explain each step of the method to you, as you can look through the code yourself.

Comment: @VinceEmigh It is not a halt or a bug I doubt. This is a pretty normal communication behaviour, and I am just interested in what is happening in details. The reason is, write function writes a data to the channel. But I observe the time consumed is related to the latency between two ends, so I doubt this function is probably waiting for the ack from the other end. But anyway, I will try use the debugger and get back any findings in this thread:D